# USB port number

Tags: embedded, usb

I have a device that I need to program from my computer. It uses a serial to usb cable to communicate with my computer. When programming the device I have to provide the port number, `ttyUSBn`. How do I know the number of the USB port I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a MAC/OSX you can use the following in a terminal window: ls /dev/tty.*

Comment: On pretty much any unix-like OS you can use that, with possibly slight variation in the file name stem.  However, it's not necessarily trivial to tell which /dev/ttyUSBn entry is the target device if there are multiples.  That's a problem with using generic serial-usb converters in products...  Sometimes you can tell from the brand/chipset of the driver which is which, or if it was plugged in after boot, the order it appears in log messages from the kernel